# Fuzzy matching to reference table

Tags: python, r

I am trying to match non-standard medical diagnosis description to ICD10 reference table description to get ICD10 code. The will be fuzzy matching. for example,

I would like to match "TRANSIENT ISCHEMIC ATTACK" to "Transient cerebral ischemic attack, unspecified" (ICD10 code G45.9). OR "INTRACTABLE NAUSEA, VOMITING" to "Nausea with vomiting, unspecified" (ICD10 code R11.2).

What would be the best way to do this type of fuzzy matching using R or python?

I looked at stringdist package in R for various 'string distance' measures with mixed success. I am also considering bag-of-word technique, but I don't know how to use it when using it in my situation. As I am comparing small strings than document of text.

Thanks

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921346/r-which-rows-have-longest-partial-string-match-between-two-vectors

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?  I am unsure how many columns you have and what result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found fuzzywuzzy by searching `fuzzy match Python`.  I don't have experience with using it, but it seems like it might do this.

"Fuzzy string matching like a boss. It uses Levenshtein Distance to help calculate differences between sequences in a simple to use package."

[fuzzywuzzy on github](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383044/fuzzy-string-comparison), which has answers that might be relevant to your problem.  Specifically, the concept of scoring how strong a match it is would be useful.

There is also a tag here on stackoverflow (`fuzzy-comparison`) that might yield more clues.